# Why is my rotate animation all wonky when applied to an Activity transition?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

What is the below animation supposed to do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

Easy enough. It should represent a *clockwise* rotation about the centre. Just spin around once, then stop. Right?

And so it does... when I apply it to a View.

But when I animate an activity transition instead, something entirely different happens. The activity starts to rotate *counterclockwise*, but at the same time it flies off the top right of the screen. Then it comes back, still rotating counterclockwise and by now upside-down, and flies off the bottom left of the screen. Finally, it comes back and ends its rotation upright.

No matter what I specify for `pivotX` and `pivotY`, the behaviour is always the same. They seem to be ignored completely. And either way, the thing is certainly not rotating around any fixed pivot at all!

**What kind of nonsense is this? Is it a bug?**

For completeness, I saved this animation as `res/anim/spin.xml`, and invoke it as follows:

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.spin, R.anim.spin);
```

(Using the same animation for both in and out makes no sense, but this is the minimal example.)

---

### Update: Demo app to reproduce this issue

I've put together a minimal Android project that demonstrates the problem. The main activity looks like this:

```
package com.example.animtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        setContentView(rootView);
    }

    public void animateRootView(View view) {
        Animation spin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.spin);
        rootView.setAnimation(spin);
        spin.start();
    }

    public void animateActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.example.animtest", "com.example.animtest.MainActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.spin, R.anim.spin);
    }

}
```

Here are the [ZIP file with the project source](http://thomas.home.fmf.nl/animtest.zip) and the [runnable APK file](http://thomas.home.fmf.nl/animtest.apk). Tested on Nexus One, Android 2.2.2.

Comment: I have the same problem (just started looking into animations, though). Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

known issue .. till 2.3.4 nothing has been done :(
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10402

Comment: thx for accept my answer, but may be you guys leav a comment on this issue. google may have a bigger push to fix this ....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like we don't quite support rotation animations on Activities :)

Comment: It does sound like that. Then why is it documented, and why doesn't the documentation tell me this rather important fact?

Comment: Would it then be possible for you to please file an internal and/or public bug for this, Romain?